# Conditional inside for loop affects loop variable increment

Tags: vba, loops, conditional-statements

Problem:
While counting number in a number series, how do I detect when I hit a milestone defined as a separate index array, like this:

```vb
Dim sects As Variant
sects = Array(0, 3, 9, 14, 26, 29)

Dim i, N As Integer
N = 30
For i = sects(0) To N
    Dim m As Integer
    m = 1
    For m = 1 To sects.Count
        MsgBox ("i, m = " + CStr(i) + "," + CStr(m))
        If i > sects(m) Then
            MsgBox ("i > sects(m) = " + CStr(i) + "," + CStr(sects(m)) + ", " + CStr(m))
        End If
    Next m
Next i
```

Expectation:
For every `i`, to see the first message box pop up a few times before the second one.
The inner loop should loop until `m` hits `sects.Count`.

Observation:
With the above code, the inner loop always ends with `m` equal to 1.
The inner loop only runs once and then "breaks". Note that no explicit break (exit) is called.

Workaround:
Remove the If conditional.
I tried to add an `Else` clause to increment `m` manually, but there is no change in behavior.

Question:
I think I have a misunderstanding about how VBA's loop and conditional work.
After consulting tutorials I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: How does that code even run? I get a 424 error on the `For` line. A VBA array does not have a `Count` property AFAIK.

Comment: @SJR that's strange. I run it in PowerPoint 2016 on macOS

Comment: OK might help to add those tags.

Comment: @SJR I think you are right. The problem is the `sects.Count`. I must have used it because with some other objects there were a Count property. But no compiler error was raised when running the code!

Comment: Do you have any on error statements earlier in the code? You can use `ubound(sects)` instead of count, but by default arrays are zero-based so will have to adjust for that.

Comment: @SJR Thanks I've figured out the `count = Ubount(sects)-Lbound(sects)+1`, but I don't have error statements in code. The code runs without compiler woes.

Comment: >> The code runs without compiler woes. <<
Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code module (in fact, _every_ code module); then re-compile.
It will highlight a lot of errors

Comment: @DavidMarten Thanks for the tip. However, I failed to find where to put that code `Option Explicit On`. I've tried: 1) at the first line of my subs, 2) at the top of my module, 3) project properties; All failed to compile. I referred to MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement , but that didn't help either.

Comment: Declare `Option Explicit` once at the top of *every* code module.
Doing so will highlight errors where you have failed to declare variables or got your VBA syntax wrong (like where you referenced a non-existent property like `sects.Count`) when you try to compile. You have to fix all the errors before the compile will succeed.
Annoyingly, it will only highlight one error at a time.
See here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160417092249/http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/Index.php/Option_Explicit
It refers to Access, but `Option Explicit` works in all Office VBA programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're attempting to do, but this seems more like what you're after:

```
Dim sects As Variant, i As Integer, N As Integer, m As Integer

sects = Array(0, 3, 9, 14, 26, 29)
N = 30
For i = 1 To N
  For m = 0 To UBound(sects)
    MsgBox "i, m = " & i & ", " & m
    If i > sects(m) Then
      MsgBox "i > sects(m) = " & i & ", " & sects(m) & ", " & m
    End If
  Next m
Next i
```